# VBA Nested Class

Tags: vba, class, nested, polymorphism

I have a VBA nested class that compiles, but I would like to format it better for extended use.

Currently to go into the animal/cat class, Animal.clsCat needs to be used. My question is, is there a way to use Animal.Cat instead while still retaining a class named Cat separately? I'm utilizing a form of hungarian notation due to the VBA limitation of not distinguishing between capitalized "Cat" and lowercase "cat".

Any help is appreciated.

Current:
Animal.clsCat.name

Ideal:
Animal.Cat.name

`Class clsCat`

```
Option Explicit

Dim propertyName As String

Public Property Get name() As String
    name = propertyName
End Property

Public Property Let name(ByVal propertyNameValue As String)
    propertyName = propertyNameValue
End Property

Sub NameSub(name As String)
    Debug.Print "Cats name is: " & name
End Sub

Function Speak() As String
    Speak = "says Meow!"
End Function
```

`Class clsDog`

```
Option Explicit

Dim propertyName As String

Public Property Get name() As String
    name = propertyName
End Property

Public Property Let name(ByVal propertyNameValue As String)
    propertyName = propertyNameValue
End Property

Sub NameSub(name As String)
    Debug.Print "Dogs name is: " & name
End Sub

Function Speak() As String
    Speak = "says Roof!"
End Function
```

`Class clsAnimal`

```
Option Explicit

Dim Cat As New clsCat
Dim Dog As New clsDog
Dim Fish As New clsFish

'Cat
Public Property Get Cat() As clsCat
    Set clsCat = Cat
End Property

Public Property Set clsCat(ByVal newValue As clsCat)
    Set Cat = newValue
End Property


'Dog
Public Property Get clsDog() As clsDog
    Set clsDog = Dog
End Property

Public Property Set clsDog(ByVal newValue As clsDog)
    Set Dog = newValue
End Property
```

`Module mTest`

```
Sub AnimalTest()

    Dim Animal As New clsAnimal
    'Dim Cat As New clsCat
    Dim Dog As New clsDog
    
    Animal.clsCat.name = "Cat"
    Animal.clsDog.name = "Dog"
    Cat.name = "TrueCat"
    
    ' SUB TEST
    Animal.clsCat.NameSub ("CatCat")
    Animal.clsDog.NameSub ("Doggo")
    
    ' DEBUG
    Debug.Print "---"
    Debug.Print Animal.clsCat.name
    Debug.Print Animal.clsDog.name
End sub
```

Comment: Investigate interfaces, implements and predeclared classes.   [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/)  has some great OOP examples.  I.e. a Cat, Dog etc implements an Animal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would set this up.  I simplified the code to illustrate the concepts:

**Class Cat**

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Name As String

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = m_Name
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal Value As String)
    m_Name = Value
End Property

Public Sub NameSub(Name As String)
    Debug.Print "Cats name is: " & Name
End Sub

Public Function Speak() As String
    Speak = "says Meow!"
End Function
```

**Class Animal**

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Cat As Cat

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set m_Cat = New Cat
End Sub

Public Property Get Cat() As Cat
    Set Cat = m_Cat
End Property

Public Property Set Cat(ByVal Value As Cat)
    Set m_Cat = Value
End Property
```

**Test**

```
Dim Animal As Animal
Set Animal = new Animal

Animal.Cat.Name = "Cat"
Debug.Print Animal.Cat.Name
Debug.Print Animal.Cat.Speak
Animal.Cat.NameSub "CatCat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from the example at [OOPs Concepts With Examples in java](https://medium.com/@tejasrisony17/oops-concepts-with-examples-in-java-1166a0d3772)

**References:**

[Immutable Object class in VBA – Creatable only through constructor and not via “New” keyword](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/157425/immutable-object-class-in-vba-creatable-only-through-constructor-and-not-via/)

**IAnimal.cls interface**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "IAnimal"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@Folder "OOP Example"
'@Interface

Option Explicit

Public Property Get Name() As String
End Property

Public Sub Eat()
End Sub

Public Sub Sleep()
End Sub

Public Sub MakeSound()
End Sub
```

**ICat.cls interface**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "ICat"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@Folder "OOP Example"
'@Interface

Option Explicit

Public Property Get Name() As String
End Property

Public Sub Eat()
End Sub

Public Sub Sleep()
End Sub

Public Sub MakeSound()
End Sub
```

**IDog.cls interface**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "IDog"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@Folder "OOP Example"
'@Interface

Option Explicit

Public Property Get Name() As String
End Property

Public Sub Eat()
End Sub

Public Sub Sleep()
End Sub

Public Sub MakeSound()
End Sub

Public Sub Bark()
End Sub
```

**Predeclared Static/Singleton classes containing factory/constructor and static members.**

**AnimalStatic.cls**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "AnimalStatic"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@Folder("OOP Example")
'@PredeclaredId

'@Remarks
'Animal singleton class containing static members. I.e. factory methods etc.

Option Explicit

' Singleton class cannot create instances
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Assert (Me Is AnimalStatic) ' breaks on-the-spot if assertion fails
End Sub

'@Static Animal Factory method should only be called from classes that implement an Animal
Friend Function Create(ByVal pName As String) As Animal
    With New Animal
        .Name = pName
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Function
```

**CatStatic.cls**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "CatStatic"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@Folder("OOP Example")
'@PredeclaredId

'@Remarks
'Cat singleton class containing static members. I.e. factory methods etc.

Option Explicit

' Singleton class cannot create instances
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Assert (Me Is CatStatic) ' breaks on-the-spot if assertion fails
End Sub

'@Static Factory Method
Public Function Create(ByVal pName As String) As ICat
    With New Cat
        .CreateInheritedAnimal pName
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Function
```

**DogStatic.cls**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "DogStatic"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@Folder("OOP Example")
'@PredeclaredId

'@Remarks
'Dog singleton class containing static members. I.e. factory methods etc.

Option Explicit

' Singleton class cannot create instances
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Assert (Me Is DogStatic) ' breaks on-the-spot if assertion fails
End Sub

'@Static Factory Method
Public Function Create(ByVal pName As String) As IDog
    With New Dog
        .CreateInheritedAnimal pName
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Function
```

**Instance classes**

**Animal.cls**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Animal"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@Folder "OOP Example"

Option Explicit

Implements IAnimal

Private Type TAnimal
    mName As String
End Type

Private this As TAnimal

Friend Property Get Self() As IAnimal
   Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.mName
End Property

Friend Property Let Name(ByVal value As String)
    this.mName = value
End Property

Public Sub Eat()
    Debug.Print "I can eat"
End Sub

Public Sub Sleep()
    Debug.Print "I can sleep"
End Sub

'@Abstract
Public Sub MakeSound()
    Debug.Assert False      ' Abstract method should never be called and overridden
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Interface IAnimal
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Property Get IAnimal_Name() As String
    IAnimal_Name = Me.Name
End Property

Private Sub IAnimal_Eat()
    Call Me.Eat
End Sub

Private Sub IAnimal_Sleep()
    Call Me.Sleep
End Sub

'@Abstract
Private Sub IAnimal_MakeSound()
    Debug.Assert False      ' Abstract method should never be called and overridden
End Sub
```

**Cat.cls**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Cat"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@Folder "OOP Example"

'@Remarks
'   Immutable cat object can only be created from a factory method.
'   As VBA doesn't support inheritence composition is used for the animal object being extended.

Option Explicit

Implements IAnimal
Implements ICat

Private Type TCat
    mAnimal As IAnimal
End Type

Private this As TCat

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set this.mAnimal = Nothing
End Sub

' Creates the inherited animal object
Friend Sub CreateInheritedAnimal(ByVal pName As String)
    Set this.mAnimal = AnimalStatic.Create(pName)
End Sub

Friend Property Get Self() As ICat
   Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.mAnimal.Name
End Property

Public Sub Eat()
    Call this.mAnimal.Eat
End Sub

Public Sub Sleep()
    Call this.mAnimal.Sleep
End Sub

'@Override Animal abstract method MakeSound
Public Sub MakeSound()
    Debug.Print "Meow meow.."
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Interface IAnimal
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Property Get IAnimal_Name() As String
    IAnimal_Name = Me.Name
End Property

Private Sub IAnimal_Eat()
    Call Me.Eat
End Sub

Private Sub IAnimal_Sleep()
    Call Me.Sleep
End Sub

Private Sub IAnimal_MakeSound()
    Call Me.MakeSound
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Interface ICat
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Property Get ICat_Name() As String
    ICat_Name = Me.Name
End Property

Private Sub ICat_Eat()
    Call Me.Eat
End Sub

Private Sub ICat_Sleep()
    Call Me.Sleep
End Sub

Private Sub ICat_MakeSound()
    Call Me.MakeSound
End Sub
```

**Dog.cls**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Dog"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@Folder("OOP Example")

'@Remarks
'   Immutable dog object can only be created from a factory method.
'   As VBA doesn't support inheritence composition is used for the animal object being extended.
Option Explicit

Implements IAnimal
Implements IDog

Private Type TDog
    mAnimal As IAnimal
End Type

Private this As TDog

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set this.mAnimal = Nothing
End Sub

' Creates the inherited animal object
Friend Sub CreateInheritedAnimal(ByVal pName As String)
    Set this.mAnimal = AnimalStatic.Create(pName)
End Sub

Friend Property Get Self() As IDog
   Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.mAnimal.Name
End Property

Public Sub Eat()
    Call this.mAnimal.Eat
End Sub

Public Sub Sleep()
    Call this.mAnimal.Sleep
End Sub

'@Override Animal abstract method MakeSound
Public Sub MakeSound()
    Debug.Print "Bark bark.."
End Sub

'@Extends Example method extending Animal
Public Sub Bark()
    Debug.Print "I can bark"
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Interface IAnimal
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Property Get IAnimal_Name() As String
    IAnimal_Name = Me.Name
End Property

Private Sub IAnimal_Eat()
    Call Me.Eat
End Sub

Private Sub IAnimal_Sleep()
    Call Me.Sleep
End Sub

Private Sub IAnimal_MakeSound()
    Call Me.MakeSound
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Interface IDog
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Property Get IDog_Name() As String
    IDog_Name = Me.Name
End Property

Private Sub IDog_Eat()
    Call Me.Eat
End Sub

Private Sub IDog_Sleep()
    Call Me.Sleep
End Sub

Private Sub IDog_MakeSound()
    Call Me.MakeSound
End Sub

Private Sub IDog_Bark()
    Call Me.Bark
End Sub
```

**AnimalExample.bas**

```
Attribute VB_Name = "AnimalExample"
'@Folder "OOP Example"
    
Option Explicit

Public Sub AnimalExample()
    Dim dog1 As IDog
    Set dog1 = DogStatic.Create("German Shepard")
    Debug.Print "dog1 example."
    Call DisplayAnimal(dog1)
    Debug.Print "Dog extension method Bark: ";
    Call dog1.Bark
    Debug.Print
    
    Dim cat1 As ICat
    Set cat1 = CatStatic.Create("Ragdoll")
    Debug.Print "cat1 example."
    Call DisplayAnimal(cat1)
    Debug.Print
End Sub

Public Sub DisplayAnimal(ByVal value As IAnimal)
    Debug.Print "Object type is " & TypeName(value)
    Debug.Print "Name: " & value.Name
    Call value.Eat
    Call value.Sleep
    Call value.MakeSound
End Sub

' The example displays the following output:
'    dog1 example.
'    Object type is Dog
'    Name: German Shepard
'    I can eat
'    I can sleep
'    Bark bark..
'    Dog extension method Bark: I can bark
    
'    cat1 example.
'    Object type is Cat
'    Name: Ragdoll
'    I can eat
'    I can sleep
'    Meow meow...
```